# Undefined local variable or method error Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables

I just started coding bootcamp and I am getting this error in my lab. I have tried setting the value with "" but to no avail I am still getting this error 
"undefined method `breed=' for # (NoMethodError)

So after defining correctly with "end" I am still getting this error.

I currently have:

```
class Dog
  def name=(fido)
    @name= fido
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def breed=(beagle)
    @breed= beagle
  end

  def breed
    @breed
  end
end

fido = Dog.new
fido.name = fido
fido.breed = beagle
```

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: Functions are to be opened with `def` keyword and **closed with `end`keyword**.

Comment: What a Beautiful Picture!

Comment: Sorry for posting a picture, I will not do that going forward. Thank you for the help

Comment: Aside from the missing quotes around `fido` and `beagle`, this works fine as-is. I didn't see the original image that was posted, but are you sure you don't have a simple typo?

Comment: Thanks Jim, I copied and pasted my code before putting the " ". I winded up just refreshing the program because I kept getting the error even with the corrections and no typos. After the refresh it accepted

Answer (score 0):

Some explanations. With

```
fido = Dog.new
fido.name = fido
puts "fido.name=#{fido.name}  fido.name.class=#{fido.name.class}"
fido.breed = self.beagle
```

you are using the local variable `fido` just created, and sending the method `beagle` to `self`, the default receiver when there is no explicit receiver, which in this case (outside any class) is the special object `main` provided by the Ruby interpreter :

```
$ ruby -w fido_op.rb 
fido.name=#<Dog:0x007ffdc2a5d620>  fido.name.class=Dog
fido_op.rb:22:in `<main>': undefined method `beagle' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

The class Dog could be simplified :

```
class Dog
  attr_reader   :name
  attr_accessor :breed

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

fido = Dog.new('fido')
puts "fido.name=#{fido.name}  fido.name.class=#{fido.name.class}"
fido.breed = 'beagle'
puts "fido.breed=#{fido.breed}"
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w fido.rb 
fido.name=fido  fido.name.class=String
fido.breed=beagle
```